# kubernetes - replace existing container at regular interval (5 to 10 minutes)

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade

At regular interval (usually 5 to 10 minutes)  service recvs a api call to ask it reload its dataset , after receving this request , the app waits for all existing calls to finish , then it loads the new data and start accepting new traffic (Have no control over how many active requests are there, so it may take a lot of time.

What i am thinking is --- A service has always 2 container (for availability) , we create 2 containers with new dataset and when they are ready , the existing containers are shut down - is it a good way ?
Something like a rolling

We can have around 100 of these services, any suggestions are welcome

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you check if the below mentioned link related to statefulset is useful to you. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/